# Difference in C++11 async behaviour on Mac and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, c++11, asynchronous

Consider the following C+11 code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = [start](string s) {
        cout << s << (chrono::steady_clock::now() - start).count() << endl;
    };

    elapsed("A ");
    auto fut (async([]() { this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2)); }));
    elapsed("B ");
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
    elapsed("C ");
    fut.wait();
    elapsed("D ");
    return 0;
}
```

## Mac Results

Compiling said code on macOS Sierra with the command `c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall question.cc -o question` and running, I get the output:

```
A 27186
B 86970
C 1001961755
D 2001585903
```

which is expected. It took minimal time to get to `A` and `B`, waited 1 second and then got to `C`, and waiting the remaining of the 2 seconds (1 already elapsed) to get to `D`.

The Mac compiler is:

```
$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

## Linux Results

On Linux, I compiled the same code with `c++ -std=c++11 -pthread question.cc -o question` and ran, and got the result:

```
A 32423
B 444340
C 1003635793
D 3006121895
```

The Linux compiler is:

```
$ c++ --version
c++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I also tried `clang++` on Linux, the LLVM C++ compiler. Same result.

## Q

Why is there the fully 2 second lag between `C` and `D` on Linux? Wasn't the async task supposed to run in the background? Am I using the wrong compile options?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with gcc 6.2 on Linux. C to D takes one additional second.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Compiler difference?

Comment: I can reproduce with g++ `5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2` on Linux 4.4.0-42. Mind posting the output of `strace question` on Linux?

Comment: Setting `std::launch::async` explicitly as the desired policy produces the intended behaviour on Linux as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`async` takes as an optional parameter if you want to start it in a different thread, or just wait until the `.wait` is called to run the code.

You chose "I do not care" by omitting it.

If you care, state you want it in a different thread.  If not, you should not be surprised if they waited until you `.wait`ed to run it, or alternatively started a new thread and ran it there.  In your case, one compiler made it lazy, the other put it in its own thread.  Both are permitted by the standard.

To get the behavior you expect, pass `std::launch::async` as the first argument to `std::async`.

---

Now, in theory `async` without being told how to run it is supposed to do something smart.  But some compilers punted and said "always doing it lazy is less work for us" (or always async), so did always-lazy whenever you let it.

This is a quality of implementation issue.  At this point, you cannot trust `async` to be smart on all C++11 compilers you are working with.  Come back in a decade.